# Добавление в таблицу избранного PHP,SQL

Tags: php, sql, angularjs

Я начинающий прогер и работаю джуном всего неделю.У меня стоит задача сделать "Избранное" на сайте.С помощью сессий я сделал сохранение флага в сессию с помощью PHP.Работает он правильно.Код ниже:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['favorite'][(int)$_POST['id']])) {
   $_SESSION['favorite'][(int)$_POST['id']] = 1;
} else {
    unset($_SESSION['favorite'][(int)$_POST['id']]);
}
```

Сейчас стоит задача : Товар добавлен в избранное если он добавлен через сессию, либо есть строчка в этой табличке.
т.е. нужно при записи писать и в сессию, и в БД. а при чтении работает условие или.

Я реализовал это следующим образом,но работает некорректно, при неоднократном обновлении страницы ,строчки в таблице дублируются и если убрать флажок избранного на странице товара и перейти обратно в каталог товаров,то товар останется выделен Избранным и не будет удален из таблицы, удален будет только тогда когда я перезагружу страницу.Надеюсь доходчиво объяснил. Помогите пожалуйста у меня мало опыта,а проект очень большой. Подумываю может даже о найме и сотрудичестве с ментором.

Код на странице каталога товаров (директиву не прикрепляю)

```
<div class="favoriteContainer" vg-favorite data-id="<?= $good['id'] ?>" data-is-full="true"
             data-is-favorite="<?= $_SESSION['favorite'][$good['id']] ?>"></div>
```

Код на странице товара:

```
 <div vg-favorite data-id="<?= $id ?>" data-is-full="true"
 
                     data-is-favorite="<?= !empty($_SESSION['favorite'][$id]) ?>"></div>
                <div>
```

PHP код

```
$favorite = $_SESSION['favorite'][$id];
$userId = $_SESSION['currentUser'];
$favoriteCatalog = $_SESSION['favorite'][$good['id']];
$goodId = $good['id'];
 
if (empty($_SESSION['favorite'][(int)$_POST['id']])) {
    $_SESSION['favorite'][(int)$_POST['id']] = 1;
    if (empty($favorite)) {
        mysqli_query(DB::db(), "DELETE FROM users_goods WHERE GOOD_ID = '$id'");
    } else {
        mysqli_query(DB::db(), "INSERT INTO users_goods (GOOD_ID,USER_ID) VALUE ('$id','$userId')");
    }
    if (empty($favoriteCatalog)) {
        mysqli_query(DB::db(), "DELETE FROM users_goods WHERE GOOD_ID = '$goodId'");
    } else {
        mysqli_query(DB::db(), "INSERT INTO users_goods (GOOD_ID,USER_ID) VALUE ('$goodId','$userId')");
    }
} else {
    unset($_SESSION['favorite'][(int)$_POST['id']]);
}
```

Comment: Избранное и сейв в сессии ? Ajax, php обработчик и поле в БД..зачем для этой цели сейвить в сессии - не понятно. Вообще не ясно, зачем берете `большой проект`, если сомневаетесь в своих силах..уж тем более `кодите` без экранирования переменных...заказчику явно не понравится уничтоженная `таблица` через некоторое время

Comment: Такую задачу мне поставил прогер,который принимал меня на работу и у которого я нахожусь в подчинении .Поскольку это мой первый опыт и моя первая задача, то выбора у меня нет, приходится делать,искать писать,но сейчас я уперся в тупик ,поэтому прошу Вашей помощи.

Comment: Сделал Вам небольшой пример

Answer (score 0):

Накидал пример на коленке. Переделаете, проверите на ошибки, доведете до ума и закончите мысль уже самостоятельно. Максимум для чего я бы юзал сессию - для хранения идентификатора авторизованного юзера для сравнений и проверок..но не для другого

**Страница с товаром**

```
<?
//проверяете, есть ли данный артикул у юзера в избранных. Если нет, то
echo '<button class="add" data-article="2212">Добавить в избранное</button>';
//Иначе
echo '<button class="remove" data-article="2212">Удалить из избранных</button>';


?>
```

**JS НА СТРАНИЦЕ С ТОВАРОМ**

```
$('.add').click(function(){
var article = $(this).attr('data-article');
addRelated(article);
});
function addRelated(article) {
    var uid = "<?= $ИДЕНТИФИКАТОР_ТЕКУЩЕГО_ЮЗЕРА ?>";
    var article = article;
    var url = "ПУТЬ_ДО_ОБРАБОТЧИКА"
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: 0,
        data: {
            "uid": uid,
            "action" : "addRelated",
            "article": article,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.error == false)
            {
                console.log(data.message); //Сообщение без ошибки выводится в консоль 
                разработчика.

                // тут же если необходимо, визуальные красоты делаете.. меняете 
                содержимое и т.п.
            }else{
                console.log(data.message); //Сообщение с ошибкой
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {}
    })
}
```

**PHP обработчик**

```
// Углубляться не буду. По основам
// Представим, что наш $_POST['uid'],$_POST['article'] состоит только из целых чисел.
// Как вариант, экранируем через preg_replace. В данном примере удалятся абсолютно все символы, кроме цифр..

$uid = preg_replace('/[^\d]/u', '',$_POST['uid']);
$article = preg_replace('/[^\d]/u', '',$_POST['article']);

if ($_POST['action'] == 'addRelated') //Если мы добавляем в избранное
{
    $bds = new mysqli(...);
    // Теперь, зная о том, какой пользователь нажал кнопку и какой артикул товара он хочет добавить в избранное, действуем.
    // Для примера я буду писать все в 1 ячейку столбца, хотя, это не всегда хорошее действие...но для примера подойдет

    // Сначала достаем все данные с ячейки и делаем строку массивом
    $query = $bds->query("SELECT related FROM users WHERE user_id='$uid'");
    $getArray = $query->fetch_array();

    $getRelatedList = explode(',',$getArray[0]);

    //Проверяем, нет ли такого товара уже в избранных, чтобы нельзя было дублировать и т.п.
    if (!in_array($article,$getRelatedList))
    {
       array_push($getRelatedList,$article); //Добавляем данный артикул в массив избранных
       $getList = implode(',',$getRelatedList); //Делаем из массива обратно строку

       $bds->query("UPDATE users SET related='$getList' WHERE user_id='$uid'");

       //Возвращаем уведомление юзеру, что все ок
       echo json_encode(['error'=>false,'message'=>'Товар добавлен в избранное']);
       return;
    }else{
       //Возвращаем ошибку, что товар уже есть
       echo json_encode(['error'=>true,'message'=>'Товар уже был добавлен ранее']);
       return;
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большущее,что-то начинает проясняться,завтра попробую реализовать у себя.

Answer (score 0):

В общем реализовано таким образом:

$id = (int)$_POST['id'];

$user = User::user();

if (empty($_SESSION['favorite'][$id])) {

```
$_SESSION['favorite'][$id] = 1;

if( !empty( $user ) ){

    mysqli_query(DB::db(), "INSERT INTO users_goods (GOOD_ID,USER_ID) VALUE ('$id','$user[id]')");
}
```

} else {

```
unset($_SESSION['favorite'][$id]);

if( !empty( $user ) ){
    
    mysqli_query(DB::db(), "DELETE FROM users_goods WHERE GOOD_ID = '$id' AND USER_ID = " . $user['id']);
}
```

}